# Python: slice array uniformly with respect to dataset

Tags: python, arrays, distribution, post-processing

I have a data set that has time `t` and a data `d`. Unfortunately, I changed the rate of exporting the data after some time (the rate was too high initially). I would like to sample the data so that I effectively remove the high-frequency exported data but maintain the low-frequency exported data near the end.

Consider the following code:

```
arr = np.loadtxt(file_name,skiprows=3)
```

Where `t = arr[:,0], d = arr[:,1]`.

Here is a function to get a uniform slicing:

```
def get_uniform_slices(arr, N_desired_points):
    s = arr.shape
    if s[0] > N_desired_points: 
        n_skip = m.ceil(s[0]/N_desired_points)
    else:                     
        n_skip = 1
    return arr[0::n_skip,:] # Sample output
```

However, the data then looks fine for the high-frequency exported data, but is too sparse for the low-frequency exported data.

Is there some way to slice such that indexes are uniformly spaced with respect to `t`?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is function I used to find the indexes, based on the accepted answer:

```
def get_uniform_index(t,N_desired_points):
    t_uniform = np.linspace(np.amin(t),np.amax(t),N_desired_points)
    t_desired = [nearest(t_d, t) for t_d in t_uniform]
    i = np.in1d(t, t_desired)
    return i
```

Comment: can you [`np.interp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) the data?

Comment: I prefer to maintain the original data..

Comment: Sure, but if you interp to exactly the points that you want to maintain, then you shouldn't have a problem...

Comment: Ok, then I suppose so.

Comment: I'm trying to go from high to low frequency data, not the other way around @mgilson. Although, I suppose I could interpolate to high frequency and then sample uniformly. Is that your suggestion?

Comment: Have a look at [pandas.resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

Comment: I'll take a look into this, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2d data e.g.,

```
t = np.arange(0., 100., 0.5)
d = np.random.rand(len(t))
```

You want to keep only particular values of data at uniformly spaced times, e.g.

```
t_desired = np.arange(0., 100., 1.)
```

Let's pick them out the data points desired at the times desired using the `in1d` function:

```
d_pruned = d[np.in1d(t, t_desired)]
```

Of course, you must pick the `t_desired` and they should match values in `t`. If that's a problem, you could pick approximately uniform times using e.g.,

```
def nearest(x, arr):
    index = (np.abs(arr - x)).argmin()
    return arr[index]

t_uniform = np.arange(0., 100., 1.)
t_desired = [nearest(t_d, t) for t_d in t_uniform]
```

Here is the complete code:

```
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0., 100., 0.5)
d = np.random.rand(len(t))

def nearest(x, arr):
    index = (np.abs(arr - x)).argmin()
    return arr[index]

t_uniform = np.arange(0., 100., 1.)
t_desired = [nearest(t_d, t) for t_d in t_uniform]

d_pruned = d[np.in1d(t, t_desired)]
```

Comment: I think in1d is a good idea once I know what `t_desired` is, but that's the trickiest part I think. Is there a way to automatically determine `t_desired`?

Comment: It's your dataset, not sure how I can answer that. Is your time data uniformly spaced?

Comment: Difficult to answer w/o more info about your data. I've added a suggestion.

Comment: Ah, I see! I think your suggestion will work! Let me verify and I'll come back.